# Get a reference to the anchor element of an Ajax.ActionLink at the OnSuccess handler

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically my question is similar or even a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012599/asp-net-mvc-get-reference-to-triggerelement-in-onsuccess-function) one, except that I'm using MVC Razor. And I'm certain that the answers there are outdated since the client library currently used is jQuery / unobtrusive ajax.

So to sum up the question, I'm trying to access the anchor element that triggered the Ajax request in the handler specified at the `OnSuccess` property of the provided `AjaxOptions`.

Here is the `ActionLink`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add opening times entry", "AddOpeningTimes", 
  new { htmlPrefix = Html.HtmlPrefixFor(m => Model.OpeningTimes) },
  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "openingTimes",
    InsertionMode =  nsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    OnSuccess = "updateHtmlPrefix" },
  new { title = "Add opening times entry" })
```

JS:

```
function updateHtmlPrefix() {
  this.href = this.href.replace(/\d(?=]$)/, function (i) { return ++i; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a link to an answer that shows several solutions and a good mark explanation of the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068946/1563373

you could always just write

```
 OnBegin="function() { clickedLink = $(this); }"
```

You can then access the clickedLink variable in the success handler (remember to declare it with page scope).

EDIT:

After some playing around with the call stack, you could try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function start(xhr) {        
        var stack = start.caller;
        // walk the stack
        do {
            stack = stack.caller;            
        } while (stack.arguments != undefined && stack.arguments.length > 0 && (stack.arguments[0].tagName == undefined || stack.arguments[0].tagName != "A"))
    //stack now points to the entry point into unobtrusive.ajax
    if (stack.arguments != undefined)
        xhr.originalElement = $(stack.arguments[0]);

    //blech        
}

function UpdateHrefText(result, status, xhr) {
    debugger;
    if(xhr.originalElement != undefined)
        xhr.originalElement.text(result.Message);
}
</script>


@Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "Message", "Home", new AjaxOptions{ OnBegin = "start", OnSuccess = "UpdateHrefText"})
```

Not sure I would trust this in production though.  I'd do something more like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theLink;

function start(xhr) {
    xhr.originalElement = theLink;        
}

function UpdateHrefText(result, status, xhr) {
    debugger;
    if(xhr.originalElement != undefined)
        xhr.originalElement.text(result.Message);
}
</script>


@Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "Message", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions{ OnBegin = "start", OnSuccess = "UpdateHrefText"}, new { onclick="theLink = $(this);"})
```

Comment: you are right, i didn't click the link, apologies.  having tackled issues like this just last year, I came across the same issue, the original target is not fed forward.  The solutions provided in the answer linked are still valid now.

Comment: I tried your first method, I debugged it and the `start` function throws the following error: *'"onMessageExternal" can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.'*, When the updateHrefText is reached, the xhr.originalElement is undefined.

Comment: Looks like xhr cannot be defined. Is there another nice way to do it, surely I prefer to avoid using external global variables.

Comment: The first example works - it gets to the element, the but the `xhr.element` remains `undefined`.

Comment: both examples worked when i tested them.  in terms of the second, the global variable is short lived, as it is accessed in the onbegin and pushed into the request context, so users clicking another button would have to be quick (ie. lightning quick) to force the btn to be assign to the wrong context, makes it pretty safe in my book.  the other option is to alter the unobtrusive ajax file to add it in to the request.

Comment: what does the xhr have in it when it returns from the method call? On the second method, does theLink veriable have the link in it when start is called?